# Twitter4j Android Dialog WebView

Tags: android, webview, dialog, android-webview, twitter4j

How to implement twitter4j authentication in webview inside a dialog ? Including listener to it so we could handle when our user cancel the authentication (pressing back button) or failed to authenticate etc..

P.S:
I've search for any complete implementation for authenticating and updating status via twitter4j using a webview [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.com/2011/12/android-twitter-login-using-twitter4j.html) . But the tutorial doesn't provide complete code to implement it.

So the authentication process would appear like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zClnh.png)

Would you give a **Complete Example** ? i am newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also meet the sampe problem. see this [post](http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.in/2011/06/for-all-my-code-thirsty-friends-twitter.html) and this [git](https://code.google.com/p/twitter-android/source/browse/library/src/com/codegoogle/twitterandroid/TwitterSession.java) it might help you.